# How to pass the same values to every view in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I've got a list I need to pass to every view in Grails. How to do it in a clean way?
I can obviously pass it in render in every action, but it does not seem to be clean solution.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// grails-app/conf/MyCustomFilters.groovy
class MyCustomFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            // this is executed after the controller action and before the view is rendered
            after = { Model model ->
                model?.listOfNames = ['Jeff', 'Betsy', 'Jake', 'Zack']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define simple custom [filter](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html) and add your list to `params` map:

```
class MyCustomFilter {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            before = {
                params.list = [1, 2, 3]
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`params` map is available in all of your controllers.

Comment: I am not sure why this answer was accepted but it is wrong.  The question is about passing data to every view.  This code is adding data in the other direction by adding a request parameter to ever request.

Comment: As I mentioned this method will add the list to parameters map which is available in every controller. I haven't tested your answer but it seems to be better, it does exactly what the question was about. Upvote :)

Comment: The question says "I've got a list I need to pass to every view in Grails.".  I interpreted that to mean that he wants the list in the model that is passed to the view.  Putting the data in the request parameters is not the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I know - that's why I said that your answer is better.

Comment: I see.  My mistake.  When you said "Upvote", I thought you were directing me to upvote your answer.  Now I understand.  Sorry for the confusion (it was my fault).

Comment: No problem :) Thanks for providing better answer!